# Xcode 6. Create custom view from nib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, interface-builder, custom-view

I'm trying to create my custom view that will be loaded from nib file.

So I have 3 files: CustomView.h, CustomView.m, CustomView.xib.

As I need this view in my storyboard, I'm trying to load it in `initWithCoder:` method:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self != nil) {
        UIView *view = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] loadNibNamed:KVBTimerViewNibName owner:self options:nil].firstObject;
        [self addSubview:view];
    }

    return self;
}
```

But in this case view size is much more bigger than I need(I need the same size as my view has).

I tried to add constraints for width and height, but them I'm getting runtime error:

```
    2015-06-22 16:17:27.492 KVBTimer[8289:993411] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e0bf19090 V:[KVBTimerView:0x7f9e0bf18a90(250)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e0bf1bda0 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f9e0bf1fba0]   (Names: '|':KVBTimerView:0x7f9e0bf18a90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e0bf1f700 UIView:0x7f9e0bf1fba0.bottom == KVBTimerView:0x7f9e0bf18a90.bottom>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e0bf2dfe0 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x7f9e0bf1fba0.midY == + 57>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e0bf1f700 UIView:0x7f9e0bf1fba0.bottom == KVBTimerView:0x7f9e0bf18a90.bottom>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-06-22 16:17:27.494 KVBTimer[8289:993411] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e0bf1b560 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f9e0bf1fba0](LTR)   (Names: '|':KVBTimerView:0x7f9e0bf18a90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e0bf1bc80 UIView:0x7f9e0bf1fba0.right == KVBTimerView:0x7f9e0bf18a90.right>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e0bf1a090 KVBTimerView:0x7f9e0bf18a90.width == UIView:0x7f9e0bf1eee0.width>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e0bf2db80 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x7f9e0bf1fba0.midX == + 223.5>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e0bd32960 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7f9e0bf1eee0(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e0bf1bc80 UIView:0x7f9e0bf1fba0.right == KVBTimerView:0x7f9e0bf18a90.right>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

New code is:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self != nil) {
        UIView *view = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] loadNibNamed:KVBTimerViewNibName owner:self options:nil].firstObject;
        [self addSubview:view];
        NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

    [self addConstraint:topConstraint];
    [self addConstraint:bottomConstraint];
    [self addConstraint:leftConstraint];
    [self addConstraint:rightConstraint];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Maybe somebody already have code that works? Or can explain where is my problem?

Here is a [sample project](https://github.com/VasylKhmil/KVBTimer). Timer view is not in the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to use constraints set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints for created view:

```
subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

add constraints, for example:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

[self addConstraint:topConstraint];
[self addConstraint:bottomConstraint];
[self addConstraint:leftConstraint];
[self addConstraint:rightConstraint];
```

it works for me

Comment: copied your code, but getting the same error with constraints

Comment: you should change         self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO to view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO. And do it after addSubview

Answer (score 1):

Add this method in CustomView.m file

```
+ (id)createCustomView{
CustomView *customView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
// make sure customView is not nil or the wrong class!
if ([customView isKindOfClass:[CustomView class]])
{
    return customView;
}
else
    return nil;}
```

and in CustomView.h file add `+ (id)createCustomView;`

and call this static method with class name to where you are creating object of it.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableHeaderView"
                                                                owner:self
                                                              options:nil] objectAtIndex:0
                                   ];
```

Comment: The problem is in constraints. Not in owner. I need to handle view from nib size properly.